# run a large number of S3 copy command

Tags: amazon-web-services, shell, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have a requirement where we'll be running a large no of the copy command on S3
like

```
aws s3 cp s3://ABC/pqr/1/1157181.json s3://ABC/xyz/1/1157181.json
aws s3 cp s3://ABC/pqr/7/1157182.json s3://ABC/xyz/7/1157182.json
aws s3 cp s3://ABC/pqr/13/1157183.json s3://ABC/xyz/13/1157183.json
aws s3 cp s3://ABC/pqr/14/1157181.json s3://ABC/xyz/14/1157181.json
aws s3 cp s3://ABC/pqr/29/1157182.json s3://ABC/xyz/29/1157182.json
aws s3 cp s3://ABC/pqr/33/1157183.json s3://ABC/xyz/33/1157183.json
.
.
.
aws s3 cp s3://ABC/pqr/n/1157277.json s3://ABC/xyz/n/1157277.json
```

There are a few million of these commands. I can run them as a shell script file.

However it's very slow, I was wondering if there is a better way to run this.

Comment: Are you able to run `s3 sync` instead?  It can be significantly faster.

Comment: Sadly no, there are other files in the bucket as well and these are very specific files.

Comment: Each `aws` instance need to launch a new process, connect to S3 on it's own, and other overhead.  You'll be much better off if you can script this in some language like Python, where that overhead doesn't occur, and you could use multi-processing or some other parallelization technique as well.

Comment: See if [S3 Batch Operations](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/features/batch-operations/) has the granularity you need.

Comment: Did you try `aws s3 cp s3://ABC/pqr  s3://ABC/xyz --recursive`?

Comment: Are the files being copied totally random, or is there some pattern to the files that are included? For example, is it all files with a `.json` extension, or all files in particular subdirectories? In general, it will **perform faster if you run the command from an Amazon EC2 instance** (even small ones are fine, since it is just sending an API call). You can also **divide the script into several smaller scripts** and run them in parallel.

Comment: Another good option would be using `rclone` CLI to sync your storages: `rclone sync source:/source-bucket destination:/destination-bucket`. It does add more control over bandwidth, progress and checksum. Have a look on this article: https://forum.rclone.org/t/migrate-from-s3-to-another-s3-150tb/

Comment: @WalterA I do not want to copy all the files from those folders

Comment: @oieduardorabelo there are files with different extensions also there are a lot of files that I do not want to copy as they might overwrite other files.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein there are very specific files being copied. As for the approach of running multiple smaller scripts in parallel on the EC2 is concerned, yes that is my backup approach but even that will take 7-10 days to complete.

Comment: @jarmod I looked into the S3 batch, but unfortunately, as of yet it does not have the option to specify multiple destinations.

Comment: The AWS CLI is _very_ good at copying files in parallel, but for that it needs to copy whole directories rather than single files. If "total time" is your concern, then it might actually be faster to simply copy whole directories (or the whole bucket?) since it will run significantly faster. The extra speed might make up for having to copy more files than required. Alternatively, you could write your own code in some programming language that uses multiple threads to send API calls in parallel rather than making sequential Copy requests. This program could use a list of filenames as input.

Comment: On the S3 Batch concern about multiple destinations, if I understand what you're doing,  can't that simply be multiple operations with the same source and one destination each? If you're doing this at large scale, you really don't want to build the orchestration if you don't have to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After not finding any solution for my specific scenario, I did the following to execute millions of AWS S3 cli commands

1. Generate an EC2 instance with s3 permissions.
2. Copy the file with all my commands to the EC2 instance.
3. Split the command file either manually or using **split** command

   split -l 200000 commands.sh -d -a 1 commands.sh
4. Generate a new shell script file that runs all the split command files, like

   sh command.sh0 > command0.log &
   sh command.sh1 > command1.log &
5. additionally you can add individual logs by using '**>**'
   and by using '**&**' you can run the command in the background.
6. finally using '**ps aux**' we can monitor the status of execution.